# Как выполнить 2 запроса сразу mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Ошибка:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '1' at line 1

А вот сам код:

```
<?php
include_once 'database.php';
$sucess = "";

if(isset($_POST['save']))
{    
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $product  = $_POST['product'];
    $price  = $_POST['price'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];


    if (mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tovar (name,product,price,email)
    VALUES ('$name','$product','$price','$email')" && "UPDATE stuck SET sht = (sht - 1) WHERE id='$uid'")) // вот здесь и есть ошибка. не знаю я использовал и `, ; &&` но ничего не получается 
    {
        $sucess = "Insert has been successfully.!";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "
    " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

У меня две таблицы - stuck и tovar. Необходимо при нажатии на кнопку отправлять данные в этот код (в process.php) и обновлять данные в таблицах

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, `&&` замените на `;` и уберите кавычки:

```
"INSERT INTO tovar (name,product,price,email)
    VALUES ('$name','$product','$price','$email'); 
 UPDATE stuck SET sht = (sht - 1) WHERE id='$uid'"
```

во-вторых, mysqli_query() можно использовать только для 1 запроса, если их больше необходимо использовать [mysqli_multi_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: InDevX а вы б могли сделать пример на моем коде?